# How to override the getMappingForMethod method in springMVC's RequestMappingHandlerMapping

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc

1. First I do one override to the RequestMappingHandlerMapping as below

   ```
   public class RestAnnotationHandler extends RequestMappingHandlerMapping{
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

   @Override
   protected RequestMappingInfo getMappingForMethod(Method method, Class<?> handlerType) {
         RequestMappingInfo info = null;

   List<RequestMethod> requestMethod = new ArrayList<>(RequestMethod.values().length);
   String[] value = null;
   if(method.isAnnotationPresent(Post.class)){
       Post postAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, Post.class);
       requestMethod.add(RequestMethod.POST);
       value = postAnnotation.value();
   }else if(method.isAnnotationPresent(Get.class)){
       Get getAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, Get.class);
       requestMethod.add(RequestMethod.GET);
       value = getAnnotation.value();
   }else if(method.isAnnotationPresent(Put.class)){
       Put putAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, Put.class);
       requestMethod.add(RequestMethod.PUT);
       value = putAnnotation.value();
   }else if(method.isAnnotationPresent(Delete.class)){
       Delete deleteAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, Delete.class);
       requestMethod.add(RequestMethod.DELETE);
       value = deleteAnnotation.value();
   }else if(method.isAnnotationPresent(RequestMapping.class)){
       RequestMapping annotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(method, RequestMapping.class);
       requestMethod.addAll(Arrays.asList((annotation.method()!=null && annotation.method().length>0)?annotation.method():RequestMethod.values()));
       value = annotation.value();
   }

   final String[] requestMappingValue = value;
   if(requestMethod.size() > 0){
       final RequestMethod[] requestMappingRequestMethod = requestMethod.toArray(new RequestMethod[requestMethod.size()]);
       logger.info("Open a web rest annotation: {} and method {}!", requestMappingValue, requestMappingRequestMethod.toString());
       RequestMapping methodAnnotation  = new RequestMapping() {
           @Override
           public Class<? extends Annotation> annotationType() {
               return RequestMapping.class;
           }

           @Override
           public String name() {
               return "";
           }

           @Override
           public String[] value() {
               return requestMappingValue;
           }

           @Override
           public String[] produces() {
               return new String[]{};
           }

           @Override
           public String[] params() {
               return new String[]{};
           }

           @Override
           public RequestMethod[] method() {
               return requestMappingRequestMethod;
           }

           @Override
           public String[] headers() {
               return new String[]{};
           }

           @Override
           public String[] consumes() {
               return new String[]{};
           }

           @Override
           public String[] path() {
               return requestMappingValue;
           }
       };

       RequestCondition<?> methodCondition = getCustomMethodCondition(method);
       info = createRequestMappingInfo(methodAnnotation, methodCondition);
       RequestMapping typeAnnotation = AnnotationUtils.findAnnotation(handlerType, RequestMapping.class);
       if (typeAnnotation != null) {
           RequestCondition<?> typeCondition = getCustomTypeCondition(handlerType);
           info = createRequestMappingInfo(typeAnnotation, typeCondition).combine(info);
        }
      }
     return info;
   }

   }
   ```
2. then I config it in spring context.xml loaded by org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener, so this bean will be in root WebApplicationContext.

   ```
   <bean id="RequestMappingHandlerMapping" class="com.hisoka.handler.RestAnnotationHandler"/>
   ```
3. Now we can use my rest Annotation to annotate one control method, and i can visit that method on browser.

   ```
   @Documented
   @Target(ElementType.METHOD)
   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   public @interface Get {

      String[] value() default{};

   }

   @Get("/")
   @ResponseBody
   public ModelAndView index() {
      Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      result.put("name", "Hinsteny");
      return new ModelAndView("home").addObject("name", "Hinsteny Hisoka");
   }
   ```
4. But when i config DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler to deal static resource, and myself rest Annotation can't work properly

   ```
   <mvc:default-servlet-handler/>
   ```

Question: How to make my rest Annotation and DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler work together in springmv? please help me